# Select Statement to loop through another javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, coldfusion

Okay So I have a select statement that needs to populate a loop in a javascript. I have very very basic knowledge of JS. I have some very basic coldfusion here that I am using. Problem is one is client side and the other server-side.

I need the first select statement to loop through where my cfloop is inside the javascript. I need to somehow change that to a javascript loop (where it says $(document).ready(function(){). I don't know how. Can anyone help?

```
    <cfoutput>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='/jquery-1.8.2.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeHiddenInput (objDropDown)
    {
        var objHidden = document.getElementById("hiddenInput");
        objHidden.value = objDropDown.value; 
    }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <cfquery name="Types" datasource="DSN">
    SELECT  Taking.*, Type.*
    FROM    Taking 
    INNER JOIN  Type ON Taking.Taking_TypeID = Type.Type_ID
    ORDER BY    Type_ID
    </cfquery>

    <form>How many to change?
       <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown" onchange="changeHiddenInput(this)">
        <cfloop index="ABC" from="1" to="12" step="1">
            <option value="#ABC#">#ABC#</option>
        </cfloop>
       </select>

       <input type="text" name="hiddenInput" id="hiddenInput" value="" />
    </form>

    <br>
    <br>
    <cfset Changing=4>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    <cfloop index="I" from="1" to="#Changing#" step="1">
    $('.box#I#').hide();
     $('##dropdown#I#').change(function() {
       $('.box#I#').hide();
       $('##div' + $(this).val()).show();
    });
    </cfloop>
    });
    </script>

    <form>
    <cfloop index="J" from="1" to="#Changing#" step="1">
    <select id="dropdown#J#" name="dropdown#J#">
    <option value="0">Choose</option>
        <cfloop query="Types" startrow="1" endrow="#Types.recordcount#">
            <option value="area#J##Type_ID#">Change over #Type_Name#</option>
    </cfloop>
    </select>
    <br>

    <cfloop query="Types" startrow="1" endrow="#Types.recordcount#">
    <div id="divarea#J##Type_ID#" class="box#J#">

        <cfquery name="GetQuestions" datasource="DSN">
        SELECT  Questions.*
        FROM    Questions 
        WHERE   Questions_OrgID=1
        AND     Questions_TypeID=#Types.Type_ID#
        ORDER BY    Questions_Rank
        </cfquery>

        <cfloop query="GetQuestions">
            #Questions_Question#<br>
        </cfloop>

    </div>
    </cfloop>
    <br>
    <br>
    </cfloop>

    </form>
    </cfoutput>
```

Comment: maybe you can elaborate on why you need to intermix ColdFusion and JS code together? PS. It seems pretty frightening to have SQL queries in what I presume "client-side" code... (Just speaking from my Java/C# experience. I don't know CF.)

Comment: @user1766760 - in a .cfm file the content in the `<cfquery />` tags will be purely server-side (and indeed any tags starting `<cf`)

Comment: In addition, you may be approaching this from the wrong angle. Can you back up and tell us what you are trying to do in plain english (not code)?

Comment: Hey guys sorry about that. this is what I want:

A person selects a number at the top 1-12.

If they select 4, 4 drop down menus will pop up which will you will have another chance to select a choice. each choice will have 4-8 questions associated with them.

Comment: @duncan I deduced as much... there are equivalent tags in Java.  Was alluding to perhaps a difference in coding philosophy. With model-view-controller models, server-side code should stay in the back-end as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do.  However you could turn something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    <cfloop index="I" from="1" to="#Changing#" step="1">
    $('.box#I#').hide();
     $('##dropdown#I#').change(function() {
       $('.box#I#').hide();
       $('##div' + $(this).val()).show();
    });
    </cfloop>
    });
```

Into something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for (var i = 1; i <= #Changing#; i++) 
    { 
        $('.box' + i).hide();
        $('##dropdown' + i).change(function() {
            $('.box' + i).hide();
            $('##div' + $(this).val()).show();
        });
    }
});
```

---

Update: in fact it sounds like it's entirely a JS solution?

```
function changeHiddenInput (objDropDown) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= objDropDown.value; i++) 
        { 
            $('.box' + i).hide();
            $('##dropdown' + i).change(function() {
                $('.box' + i).hide();
                $('##div' + $(this).val()).show();
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Duncan this is the right track.
How would I have that value #Changing# in the loop be populated from the first select menu (where you choose 1-12? There is extra code in my example because I do not know what I am doing.

Comment: ah ok.  So that becomes purely a JS answer. From `changeHiddenInput` do what you currently have in the document.ready().  You may still want to set a global JS variable from the Coldfusion for a default maximum: `var Changing = <cfoutput>#someValue#</cfoutput>;`